# How to reset channel of window.echo on changing of route reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, laravel-websockets

I am using laravel-websockets to listen to event. I have no issue on the back-end side; The issue is on the front-end side.

SCENARIO:

When I go to a specific route `post/[slug]`, the current channel is based on the current slug. When I redirect to the same route but different value of slug, the channel listens to the **first** value on page refresh and not to the current one.

```
const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {slug} = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
   window.Echo.private(`post.${slug}`).listen('PrivateEvent', e => { 
    console.log(e)
   });
  }, [slug])
}
```

Example:

On page refresh, go to `post/first-slug`. Next, click to `<Link to="/post/second-slug">About</Link>`

The example above should listen to `second-slug` and not the `first-slug`.

How can I solve this without hard refresh or `<a>` tag?

Comment: Have you tried this? This issue is still appearing.,

Comment: Does the slug change accordingly in your useEffect hook when you click the link?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to stop listening on the previous channel, so the events are still received. I suppose that you end up with two active channels, receiving events for both.

Inside a `useEffect()` you should return a cleanup function that clears resources created for the effect

Here is how:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {slug} = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
   window.Echo.private(`post.${slug}`).listen('PrivateEvent', e => { 
    console.log(e)
   });

   return () => window.Echo.private(`post.${slug}`).stopListening('PrivateEvent');
  }, [slug])
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, please:

- display the slug in your component (`return <div>slug</div>;`) to confirm that the navigation really happens ;
- show us the whole console log.